# Vagrant ssh hangs after successful boot of host

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Below is my Vagrantfile, while booting up this host, it gets stuck at

```
  ==> sawtoothclient: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
      sawtoothclient: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
      sawtoothclient: SSH username: vagrant
      sawtoothclient: SSH auth method: private key
```

Vagrant reload didnt help, I dont want to vagrant halt everytime I login on to my virtualhost.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "sawtoothclient", primary: true do |sawtoothclient|

        sawtoothclient.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
        sawtoothclient.vm.hostname ="sawtoothclient"
        sawtoothclient.vm.network :public_network
        #fubuntuone.vm.provision :shell, :privileged => false, :path => "bootstrap_ubuntu.sh"
        sawtoothclient.vm.synced_folder "/home/feynman/Programs/SawtoothClient/", "/home/vagrant/SawtoothClient/"
        sawtoothclient.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
           vb.gui = false
           vb.memory = 2048
           #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
           #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
        end

    end
end
```

My UFW firewall rules are

```
  To                         Action      From
  --                         ------      ----
  Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
```

But when I added

```
 sudo ufw allow 22
```

vagrant ssh succeeded, I couldnt understand why, From my understanding, vagrant must have been using the host machine IP to ssh into the vagrant host, which is already covered in the firewall rule added initially to the ufw firewall.

```
 Vagrant 2.1.4

 vboxmanage -v
 output: 5.2.18r124319
```